# Ubuntu 16.04: Themes stopped working, keyboard shortcuts stopped working, GUIs in fallback mode

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

All of a sudden, after a reboot, my color theme in Ubuntu 16.04 changed to the dark one, although I have selected "Radiance" in the settings. Regardless of what I select, nothing happens.

Moreover, I notice that applications like Pidgin and KeePassX look like they run in a fallback mode. For example, ccsm looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/IjXlS2n.png

Function keys also stopped working (such as F1, PrtScr).

Also, various keyboard shortcuts stop working (Ctrl+Alt+L, Super+Space,...).

I already deleted ~/.cache and the whole dconf database.

I also tried to reset compiz and unity. Nothing solves the issue.

Strangely, when I log in as another user, the desktop works fine. I compared virtually every (config) file the other user has with mine and could not spot any notable difference. So, whatever seems the problem, it seems to be outside of my home directory.

Comment: I'd like to add: I just created a new user. When I log into the system as this other user, everything seems to be OK. So apparently, a file seems to be corrupted under my main user. What should I look for?

Comment: Find files in your home directory (possibly config files) that are not owned by you: use `find ~ -not -user yourUserName`. Anything interesting there?

Comment: I was so keen to delete ~/.cache . At first, this did not have any effect. I then rebooted and everything is now working again.

Comment: Sadly, after the most recent updates and another reboot, the problem re-appeared. Deleting ~/.cache and rebooting did not solve the issue :-(

Comment: @Jos: no, not really. .rpmdb, .gvfs .

Comment: `.rpmdb` is interesting because it doesn't belong on a Ubuntu system in the first place. It belongs to the packet manager `yum` that doesn't run on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, I assume that I installed (or try to install) something that worked by converting .rpms beforehand. Anyway, all files are a year old minimum. My current assumption is that somethling like unity-settings-daemon may have a problem?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/.config/dconf`?

Comment: insgesamt 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 11916 Jun 18 11:35 user

Comment: Permissions ought to be 644 (`-rw-r--r--`), not 660 (`-rw-rw-r--`) as in your case. I'm not sure how this could be a problem, but it doesn't hurt to change that.

Comment: I changed that, but after re-login it is back to 660.